# passing a variable and calling request in the same funcion, update post in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update a contact information in database
I get contact id, ($contactid variable) from DOM, it passes to my function (postEditContact). I know it, because I tried it with delete() function and it worked fine, but I tried many different approaches, can't make it work for updating the contact.
If I use variables $contactid and $request like this postEditContact($contactid, Request $request) I get too few arguments error. If I pass only $contactid variable then I get undefined variable $request error. Please help

```
public function postEditContact($contactid, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'newname' => 'required|max:140'
    ]);

    $contact = Contact::where('id', $contactid)->first();
    $contact -> name = $request['newname'];   
    $contact -> email = $request['newe_mail'];
    $contact -> phone = $request['newphone'];
    $contact -> address = $request['newaddress'];
    $contact -> other = $request['newother'];
    $contact -> isuser = false;

    $contact -> update();
    return redirect()->route('contacts');
}
```

Comment: what about your html/form and route?

Comment: you should pass {$contactid} while updating and make sure your are submitting the post data.

Comment: can you show your routes please.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! first route is from DOM to Controller that redirects to a new view with passing variables and second is for submiting
Route::get('/edit/{contactid}', [
        'uses' => 'ContactController@getEdit',
        'as' => 'edit',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

    Route::post('/editcontact', [
        'uses' => 'ContactController@postEditContact',
        'as' => 'contact.edit',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

Comment: This is the function that passes variable
 public function getEdit($contactid)
    {    $this->postEditContact($contactid);
return view('layouts.edit'); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I was trying to pass variable from one function and and use that variable and $request in another function. I don't think I can do that. What I did is I passed the variable to a view with the first function, because it was opening a view anyway and from that view I passed the variable to another function with the route and variable. It solved the problem.